# Adjective Gradability - adj. terrible

Tags: grammar, adjectives

*I was wondering if an adjective **'terrible'** is either gradable or non-gradable. Is it correct to say:*

> It's really terrible.

Thank you in advance for an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by gradable?

Comment: @Lambie  apparently this:  https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-gradability.htm

Comment: @Andrew Gosh, that used to be called comparative/superlative. Terrible, more terrible, the most terrible.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I see. Usually referred to as comparatives and superlatives. "|It's terrible| is unchangeable. But |it's a terrible movie| is not: a terrible movie, a more terrible movie than some other one. The most terrible movie we've ever seen. So......nix.

Comment: @Lambie  I think it's more whether something can be *partially* terrible, or *a little bit* terrible, or *extremely* terrible.  As if there are grades of "terribleness".   Double-plus ungood!

Comment: I vote for "the best terrible".

Comment: @Andre Truly terrible, innit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *terrible* is generally considered to be non-gradable.  The phrase "very terrible" sounds awkward and "slightly terrible" only makes sense as an ironic or humorously self-contradictory phrase.

However, the sentence **"It's really terrible"** does sound perfectly natural to me, but that's because I don't interpret the word *really* as an intensifier in this situation, but as a synonym of *actually* or *genuinely*.  So the sentence is correct, but has the meaning, **"Actually, it's terrible."**

Comment: I agree.  "Terrible" should not be gradable -- but in practice, it's frequently graded.  "Yeah the movie wasn't **too** terrible"

Comment: It's really terrible. [the movie] It's really more terrible than that other one. It's the most terrible of all.